# Angular:Unable to detect a typescript artifact from another angular library

Tags: angular, typescript

I have made an angular library(A). I started with 'ng generate' command.

So it created classes for me inside lib folder. I put my implementation in these classes. Apart from these auto generated classes, I created two more folders in lib. One contains my service classes(@Injectable) and another one(named 'model') contains my data classes(contained in file model.ts) which are plain ts class.

So for these data classes, folder structure is:

> lib/model/model.ts

In app.module.ts, I put these classes (except data classes) under appropriate groups like imports,providers etc.

Now I am using A in a angular project, say 'my-current-angular-project'. I have added dependency in package.json, and added library in node_modules.

In this project,I do:

```
import {X, Y} from 'A/lib/model/model';
```

where X,Y are the data classes I have defined in model.ts in A(/lib/model/model.ts).

But when I do 'ng build' for this project, I get error:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
>
> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'A/lib/model/model' in 'D:\projects\my-current-angular-project\src\app'

What mistake am I making here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I got your folder structure/ question right. However, the following folder structure should work:

- your root folder of all sources `my-current-angular-project\src\`
- in this folder you can place your data classes like `my-current-angular-project\src\my_data_class.ts` where you define the `export class Data { ...` for example
- now let's assume you have generated a component with angular cli like my-component
- you now have a folder `my-current-angular-project\src\my-component\` that comprises the file `my-component.component.ts`
- in this file (`my-component.component.ts`) you can now use your dataclass like this: `import {Data } from '../my_data_class';`

Note: in this case there is no need to specify/include `my_data_class.ts` in `angular.json` or somewhere else